# Bound Apps Script are picking up from other projects

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created an apps script (bound to a Google Sheet) to send an email using a HTML template.

However, when I run the script it seems to pick up another template.

I've managed to run my template by changing the HTML file name and variable names but should this be happening considering the project is bound to my sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your script.

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using in the script, and possibly the templates you are using? Thanks

Comment: It has happened across various scripts. For example, in one of the scripts I created it was returning a random email until I changed the name of my template and variable to something unlikely to be used by anyone else (my name!).  With another script it was copying across the incorrect row because the same variable was contained in both scripts (they were bound to different forms) again had to change the variable name to make the script work.

Comment: Hello @Fazila I have posted an answer with a few tips that may help you solve your issue. If it doesn't, please consider sharing a project which has the issue you describe so that I can give tailored support. Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0):

[Scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets) (Templated HTML) in Google Apps Script, as explained in the documentation:

> [...] can call functions defined in other code files, reference global variables, or use any of the Apps Script APIs. You can even define functions and variables within scriptlets, with the caveat that they can't be called by functions defined in code files or other templates.

That means that they can access variables that are defined globally in any of your scripts. To avoid issues, I suggest you do as follows:

- Writing **all** your code inside functions. Instead of having scripts such as:

  *bad.gs*

  ```js
  function salute(name) {
    Logger.log('Hello ' + name);
  }

  salute('Jack');
  salute('Jane');
  ```

  Use a function to wrap your code; such as:

  *good.gs*

  ```js
  function salute(name) {
    Logger.log('Hello ' + name);
  }

  function myFunction() {
    salute('Jack');
    salute('Jane');
  }
  ```
- Not declaring global variables. When declaring variables, make sure that happens inside of a function and that you use the *var* keyword to do so.

  *bad.gs*

  ```js
  function salute(name) {
    Logger.log('Hello ' + name);
  }

  function myFunction() {
    names = ['Jack', 'Jane'];
    for (i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
      name = names[i];
      salute(name);
    }
  }
  ```

  *good.gs*

  ```js
  function salute(name) {
    Logger.log('Hello ' + name);
  }

  function myFunction() {
    var names = ['Jack', 'Jane'];
    for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
      var name = names[i];
      salute(name);
    }
  }
  ```
- Finally, be mindful when creating functions. In Javascript they are variables too, so they can be referenced as well. For that reason, I recommend you use appropriate names to avoid any confusion.

  *bad.gs*

  ```js
  function names() {
    return ['Jack', 'Jane'];
  }
  ```

  *good.gs*

  ```js
  function getNames() {
    return ['Jack', 'Jane'];
  }
  ```